# delete characters in lines starting with an unique pattern

Tags: regex, sed, awk, fasta

I have a file consisting of many entries that look like this:

```
>1761420406686363113470.1
CAAGATTCTGAGATAATCGCGGTTTAAAGTTTCAAATTTGTTTCGGCCGATTCGAAGTCA
```

i.e. a header line starting with > and many lines of sequence, followed by a header line. 
I am trying to write a sed script that goes to only the lines that start with > (not the sequences lines) and deletes all but the first 10 numbers.

There are a lot of similar questions to this, but I can't figure it out. I've been trying variations on this code:

```
sed 's/^>..........*/^>........../' input.fasta
```

but clearly am not doing it right..

Answer (score 3):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -r 's/^(>.{10}).*/\1/p;d' file
```

This deletes all but those lines that are substituted, if you want to retain the sequence lines:

```
sed -r 's/^(>.{10}).*/\1/' file
```

should fit the bill.

Answer (score 1):

You have to capture the first 10 characters in parentheses:

```
sed -e 's/^\(>..........\).*/\1/'
```

Which can be shortened to

```
sed -e 's/^\(>.\{10\}\).*/\1/'
```

Comment: Aren't backslashes around { and } a mistake?

Comment: @ShamirK.: It might depend on the version of `sed`. They are needed with `-e` in GNU sed.

Comment: @choroba GNU sed v4.2.1: `sed -E 's/^(>.{10}).*/\1/g'`, without backslashes

Comment: @ShamirK.: Yes, I know. But you did not use `-e` which is the most  portable. Moreover, `-E` for GNU sed is not documented (it is probably an alias for `-r`).

Comment: @choroba `-e` doesn't allow me to use backreferences

Comment: @ShamirK.: Sure it does. You have to backslash the parentheses, though.

Answer (score 1):

as an alternative to sed, use cut

```
$ echo ">1761420406686363113470.1" | cut -c1-11
>1761420406
```

To operate on lines starting with an `>`, wrap it in a bash-while-loop

```
$ while read line; do if [[ $line == \>* ]]; then cut -c1-11 <<< $line; else echo $line; fi done < input
>1761420406
CAAGATTCTGAGATAATCGCGGTTTAAAGTTTCAAATTTGTTTCGGCCGATTCGAAGTCA
```

or using awk:

```
$ awk '{if ($0 ~ />/){print substr($0,0,11)}else{print}}' input
>1761420406
CAAGATTCTGAGATAATCGCGGTTTAAAGTTTCAAATTTGTTTCGGCCGATTCGAAGTCA
```

Comment: But he only wants to truncate lines that begin with `>`, not all lines.

Comment: @Kevin That's why there's an `if` statement that checks if the line starts with `>`.

Comment: I added the if-statement after Kevins comment :-)

Answer (score 0):

Since good `sed` answers are already posted, here is an `GNU-awk solution.

```
gawk '/^>/{print gensub(/(.{11}).*/,"\\1","G",$1);next }1' inputFile
```